# python - problem converting xml data to json

Tags: python, json, xml, type-conversion

This is the xml data and code I am trying to convert into json data:

```
import xmltodict
import json

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<XML xmlns:r="#SchemaA2A">
<Schema name="SchemaA2A"  xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-data"  xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
<ElementType name="ROOT" content="eltOnly" model="closed" order="many">
<AttributeType name="Response" dt:type="i4"/>
<AttributeType name="ErrorNumber" dt:type="i4"/>
<AttributeType name="ErrorDescription" dt:type="string"/>
<AttributeType name="ErrorDisplay" dt:type="boolean"/>
<attribute type="Response"/>
<attribute type="ErrorNumber"/>
<attribute type="ErrorDescription"/>
<attribute type="ErrorDisplay"/>
</ElementType>
<ElementType name="ROW" content="empty" model="closed">
<AttributeType name="Account #" dt:type="string"/>
<AttributeType name="Tran Date" dt:type="string"/>
<AttributeType name="Post Date" dt:type="string"/>
<AttributeType name="Description" dt:type="string"/>
<AttributeType name="Reference #" dt:type="string"/>
<AttributeType name="Amt" dt:type="string"/>
<attribute type="Account #"/>
<attribute type="Tran Date"/>
<attribute type="Post Date"/>
<attribute type="Description"/>
<attribute type="Reference #"/>
<attribute type="Amt"/>
</ElementType>
</Schema>
<r:ROOT Response="1" ErrorNumber="0" ErrorDescription="" ErrorDisplay="1" >
<r:ROW Account #="xxxxxxxxxx055819" Tran Date="04/09/2020" Post Date="04/09/2020" Description="ValueLoad" Reference #="" Amt="50" />
<r:ROW Account #="xxxxxxxxxx055819" Tran Date="04/22/2020" Post Date="04/22/2020" Description="Balance Adjustment Debit Cardholder" Reference #="" Amt="-10" />
</r:ROOT>
</XML>
'''

mydict=xmltodict.parse(xml, encoding="utf-8")
json_data=json.dumps(mydict)
print(json_data)
```

It is giving back an error:

```
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 30, column 15
```

Which I believe is pointing to the end of

Really confused why I am receiving this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is not well-formed. XML element attributes cannot have whitespace or # symbols in them.

Comment: You are right,
@python_help use [XML Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-formatter) to see where are your errors